# Bookmark with date in the URL

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-analytics, bookmarks

I use Google Analytics, and the first thing I want to check every day is the current day's statistics. But there's no way to bookmark the current day.
The URL for any given day is: https://www.google.com/analytics/reporting/dashboard?id=XXXXXXX&pdr=20110921-20110921

You can see a date range at the end of the URL. 20110921 meaning 9-21, 2011.

How can I write a little javascript bookmarklet for Firefox to change the URL to the current date depending on what day I click on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - it uses a [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object to get the date:

```
var date = new Date();
var str = "";
str += date.getFullYear();
str += pad2(date.getMonth() + 1);
str += pad2(date.getDate());
function pad2(n) {
   var str = String(n);
   if(str.length < 2)
    str = "0" + str;
   return str;
}
location.href = "https://www.google.com/analytics/reporting/dashboard?id=XXXXXXX&pdr="+str+"-"+str;
```

Bookmarklet:

```
javascript:(function(){function d(a){a=String(a);a.length<2&&(a="0"+a);return a}var c=new Date,b="";b+=c.getFullYear();b+=d(c.getMonth()+1);b+=d(c.getDate());location.href="https://www.google.com/analytics/reporting/dashboard?id=XXXXXXX&pdr="+b+"-"+b})();
```

Comment: It looks like this will work great, except it causes some weird behavior in Firefox. It closes all my tabs and opens a new window which has no toolbars or URL bar or anything. Strange... Is there a way to get it to open in the current tab? I'm no pro when it comes to JS.

Comment: function pad2(n) { return '00'.slice((''+n).length)+n; }     one line pad2 function :)

Comment: @DigitalPlane Ummm, I've got Speed Dial, Adblock Plus, Session Manager, greasemonkey, and download helper

Comment: @RobHardgood I have no idea why a new window would open, especially without toolbars. I'm only setting the `location` of the current page.

Comment: @DigitalPlane It looks like it has something to do with my speed dial add on. I disabled that and it works perfectly now. So thanks for the code :D I'll figure out what's wrong with speed dial later.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript has [date methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) that can individually give the parts of a date, but [`.toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) might perhaps work for your application most concisely. Very little string manipulation would have to be performed on the result to get the UTC date in the correct format. For example:

```
javascript:
d = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10).replace(/-/g, '');
location = "https://www.google.com/analytics/reporting/dashboard?id=XXXXXXX&pdr="
           + d + "-" + d;
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on the answer by @PleaseStand - Firefox even has a non-standard [`Date.toDateLocale()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat). So the whole thing can be simplified even further:

> javascript:void(location.href = "https://www.google.com/analytics/reporting/dashboard?id=XXXXXXX&pdr=" +
>   new Date().toLocaleFormat("%Y%m%d-%Y%m%d"))

Answer (score 0):

1. Customize this code below with your Google Analytics ID, timezone offset, and other desired parameters.
2. Use a site [like this](https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) to convert JavaScript to a bookmarklet.
3. Rejoice.

   var gaID = YOUR_ID;
   var hourOffset = 8;
   var rowCount = 50;

   var utcDate = new Date(new Date().toUTCString());
   utcDate.setHours(utcDate.getHours() - hourOffset);
   var localDate = new Date(utcDate);
   var todayDate = localDate.toISOString().split("T")[0].replace(/-/g, "");

   location.href = "https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/report/advertising-adwords-keywords/" + gaID +"/_u.date00=" + todayDate + "&_u.date01=" + todayDate + "&explorer-table.plotKeys=%5B%5D&explorer-table.rowCount=" + rowCount;

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old thread, but it is still relevant.

I found that if you set up your report using todays date, then edit the URL and use a future date, it will default to the current date's statistics.

For example, I use this:

```
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/#/dashboard/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/_u.date00=20221130&_u.date01=20221130/
```

The date codes are both the same date 2 years in the future. This causes analytics to use show the current dates stats.